# What is the best way to enter the devangari add-on vowel signs to a LaTeX source file?

Tags: unicode

I have tried several answers about entering Unicode codepoint directly in LaTeX source file. But those solutions (e.g. `\symbol{}`, or `\char"....`) don't seem to work for me.

I use the velthuis mapping with the Shobhika font as my main Sanskrit text font:

```
 \newfontfamily\sanskritfont[Mapping=velthuis-sanskrit,Script=Devanagari,Language=Default]{Shobhika}
```

Everything works well as far as my *normal* devanagari typesetting is concerned. However, I am not able to seamlessly add the devanagari add-on vowel signs (e.g. ा = unicode codepoint: 093E decimal (devanagari vowel sign aa)).

How may I achieve this?

Here's my source code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec} % only for direct unicode codepoint interpretation
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguages{sanskrit}
\setmainfont[Language=English]{IBM Plex Sans}
% Other font (for Sanskrit): Shobhika
\newfontfamily\sanskritfont[Mapping=velthuis-sanskrit,Script=Devanagari,Language=Default]{Shobhika}
\begin{document}
\def\dev{\edef~{\string~}\textsanskrit}
\begin{itemize}
    \item \textsanskrit{\char"2366  --  taa}
    \item \textsanskrit{\char"2367  --  ti}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

I am expecting the `\char`s to render the add-on vowel signs, but they appear like this: [image]

Comment: it would help if you provided a complete document (with one line of text) and show what output you expect. The behaviour here is very dependent on the font and whether it supports that character.

Comment: On my Windows Browser the  ा in the question is rendered in the font `Nirmala UI` so you could use that if you have it (or in general can use whatever font your browser uses to show your question)

Comment: But I am confused you are setting up the main font with `\setmainfont[Language=English]` but using  ा in the main context not in the scope of `\sanskritfont`  ???

Comment: oh also you want `\char2366` or simply  ा`` or `\char"093E`  as `"` is hex. you are specifying hex 2366 which is a different character altogether

Comment: You can give either but you want hex 093E which is written in tex with a prefix `"` denoting hex or give the decimal with no prefix which is 2366

Comment: Got it, problem solved! I should have done `\char2366`. I forgot that `"` needs it in hex :-(. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the hex value if you prefix with `"` I have different fonts available but get

[image]

From

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec} % only for direct unicode codepoint interpretation
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguages{sanskrit}
\setmainfont[Language=English]{Arial}
% Other font (for Sanskrit): Shobhika
\newfontfamily\sanskritfont[Mapping=velthuis-sanskrit,Script=Devanagari,Language=Default]{Nirmala UI}
\begin{document}
\def\dev{\edef~{\string~}\textsanskrit}
\begin{itemize}
    \item \textsanskrit{\char"093E}  --  \textsanskrit{taa}\\
    \item \textsanskrit{\char"093F}  --  \textsanskrit{ti}\\
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```